# Google Calendar API - 404 on calendar (service account)

Tags: python, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a problem with my simple calendar API wrapper.

My code:

```
key_file = open('api_key.p12', 'rb')
key = key_file.read()
key_file.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
 config.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
 key,
 scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
)
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build("calendar", "v3", http=http)
```

And I'm calling it with:

```
service.events().insert(calendarId=calendar_id,
                               body=event_body).execute()
```

And always I have

```
HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting   https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_company_resource_id@resource.calendar.google.com?alt=json returned "Not Found">
```

When I use 'normal' OAuth2 scope (authorization in local web browser) it works, but I want to deploy my app on headless server, so I have to use Service Account. 
I granted permissions for calendar api in my google apps admin panel, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to also provide user email which has access to this calendar. See below example:

```
  credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, key,
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', sub=user_email)
```

Good example how to create credential object you can find on this page: [Instantiate a Drive service object](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#instantiate_a_drive_service_object). (Python tab). It shows example for Drive API but you can use it for Calendar API as well.